# DirectoryEntry Rename on LDAP Server

Tags: .net, vb.net, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I wrote a `VB.NET` `namespace` called **"LDAP"** to handle my LDAP connection, creation and removal. **The issue is**: I'm getting an exception thrown.

Part of the code is as written below (I removed some code that has nothing to do with the problem).

****NOTE:** the `mRoot.Rename(MainAttribute + "=" + Name)` portion.

```
    Public Function Create(ByRef User As LDAP.Credential, ByVal MainAttribute As String, ByVal Name As String, ByVal UserData As LDAP.CreationData) As Boolean
        '...
        Dim Root As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = LDAP.Connection.GetRoot(User, QueryUser:=False, KeepOpen:=True)
        If Root Is Nothing Then Return False
        Dim mRoot As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = UserData.Create(Root)
        If mRoot IsNot Nothing Then
            Try
                mRoot.CommitChanges()
                Dim newCredential As New LDAP.Credential(User.Server, User.Name, User.Password, mRoot.Name + "," + User.Node)
                Try
                    mRoot.Close()
                    mRoot = LDAP.Connection.GetRoot(newCredential, QueryUser:=False, KeepOpen:=True)
                    '... need? UserData.ApplyCreate(mRoot)
                    If UserData.Apply(mRoot) Then
                        mRoot.CommitChanges()
                        mRoot.Close()
                        mRoot = LDAP.Connection.GetRoot(newCredential, QueryUser:=False, KeepOpen:=True) 'To ensure refresh, a new load is done.
                        'MY PROBLEM IS HERE!
                        mRoot.Rename(MainAttribute + "=" + Name) 'need?: + "," + User.Node
                        '... need? mRoot.CommitChanges()
                        mRoot.Close()
                        Root.Close()
                        Return True
                    Else
                        mRoot.Close()
                        LDAP.Connection.Delete(newCredential)
                    End If
                Catch
                    mRoot.Close()
                    LDAP.Connection.Delete(newCredential)
                End Try
            Catch
                mRoot.Close()
            End Try
        End If
        Root.Close()
        Return False 'Safety, not yet working
    End Function
```

---

Question: **Why do I get the following exception**:

***DirectoryServicesCOMException***  'the requested operation doesn't meet the criteria'

on the `mRoot.Rename()` method after I run the following method:

```
Private Sub TestCreate()
    LDAP.Connection.Create(New LDAP.Credential("ldapserver.mvcompany.com.br", "cn=admin,dc=mycompany,dc=com,dc=br", "myadminpassword", "ou=people,dc=mycompany,dc=com,dc=br"), "uid", "teste.outro", New LDAP.PosixAccount("Teste", "Outro", "teste.outro", "12345", 999, 500))
End Sub
```

---

*Here is a larger code sample...*

### *LDAP.CreationData (Structure) and LDAP.Credentials (Structure)*

```
Namespace LDAP
    Public Interface CreationData
        ReadOnly Property BaseAttribute(ByVal GetValue As Boolean) As String
        Function ApplyCreate(ByRef Root As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry) As Boolean
        Function Create(ByRef MainRoot As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry) As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
        Function Apply(ByRef Root As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry) As Boolean
    End Interface

    Public Structure Credential
        Public Server As String
        Public Name As String
        Public Password As String
        Public Node As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal LdapServer As String, ByVal LdapUser As String, ByVal UserPassword As String, ByVal GroupNode As String)
            Me.Server = LdapServer
            Me.Name = LdapUser
            Me.Password = UserPassword
            Me.Node = GroupNode
        End Sub
    End Structure
```

### *LDAP.Connection (Module)*

```
Public Module Connection
    Public Function GetRoot(ByRef User As LDAP.Credential, Optional ByRef QueryUser As Boolean = False, Optional ByRef KeepOpen As Boolean = False) As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
        Dim ServerRoot As String = "LDAP://" + User.Server
        If QueryUser Then
            ServerRoot += "/" + User.Name
        ElseIf Not User.Node = "" Then
            ServerRoot += "/" + User.Node
        End If
        Try
            Dim Root As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(ServerRoot, User.Name, User.Password, System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.None)
            Dim child As Object = Root.NativeObject
            If Not KeepOpen Then Root.Close()
            Return Root
        Catch
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function Add(ByRef Root As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry, ByRef PropertyName As String, ByRef Value As Object) As Boolean
        Dim Prop As System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection = Root.Properties.Item(PropertyName)
        Try
            If Prop.Count > 0 Then Prop.Clear()
            Prop.Add(Value)
            Return True
        Catch
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function Add(ByRef Root As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry, ByRef PropertyName As String, ByRef Value() As Object) As Boolean
        Dim Prop As System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection = Root.Properties.Item(PropertyName)
        Try
            If Prop.Count > 0 Then Prop.Clear()
            Prop.AddRange(Value)
            Return True
        Catch
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function Create(ByRef User As LDAP.Credential, ByVal MainAttribute As String, ByVal Name As String, ByVal UserData As LDAP.CreationData) As Boolean
        '...
        Dim Root As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = LDAP.Connection.GetRoot(User, QueryUser:=False, KeepOpen:=True)
        If Root Is Nothing Then Return False
        Dim mRoot As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = UserData.Create(Root)
        If mRoot IsNot Nothing Then
            Try
                mRoot.CommitChanges()
                Dim newCredential As New LDAP.Credential(User.Server, User.Name, User.Password, mRoot.Name + "," + User.Node)
                Try
                    mRoot.Close()
                    mRoot = LDAP.Connection.GetRoot(newCredential, QueryUser:=False, KeepOpen:=True)
                    '... need? UserData.ApplyCreate(mRoot)
                    If UserData.Apply(mRoot) Then
                        mRoot.CommitChanges()
                        mRoot.Close()
                        mRoot = LDAP.Connection.GetRoot(newCredential, QueryUser:=False, KeepOpen:=True) 'To ensure refresh, a new load is done.
                        'MY PROBLEM IS HERE!
                        mRoot.Rename(MainAttribute + "=" + Name) 'need?: + "," + User.Node
                        '... need? mRoot.CommitChanges()
                        mRoot.Close()
                        Root.Close()
                        Return True
                    Else
                        mRoot.Close()
                        LDAP.Connection.Delete(newCredential)
                    End If
                Catch
                    mRoot.Close()
                    LDAP.Connection.Delete(newCredential)
                End Try
            Catch
                mRoot.Close()
            End Try
        End If
        Root.Close()
        Return False 'Safety, not yet working
    End Function

    Public Function Delete(ByVal User As LDAP.Credential) As Boolean
        Dim nNode As String = User.Node.Substring(0, User.Node.IndexOf(","c))
        Dim mNode As String = User.Node.Substring(nNode.Length + 1)
        User.Node = mNode
        Dim Root As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = LDAP.Connection.GetRoot(User, QueryUser:=False, KeepOpen:=True)
        Dim mRoot As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = Nothing
        Try
            mRoot = Root.Children.Find(nNode)
        Catch
            Root.Close()
            Return False
        End Try
        If mRoot Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        Else
            Try
                Root.Children.Remove(mRoot)
                Root.CommitChanges()
                Root.Close()
                Return True
            Catch
                Root.Close()
                Return False
            End Try
        End If
    End Function
End Module
```

### *LDAP.PosixAccount (structure)*

```
    Public Structure PosixAccount
        Implements LDAP.CreationData
        Public Const mainclass As String = "posixAccount"
        Public Const subclass As String = "top"
        Public Const baseclass As String = "inetOrgPerson"
        Public givenName As String
        Public sn As String
        Public uid As String
        Public uidNumber As Integer
        Public gidNumber As Integer
        Public userPassword As String

        Public ReadOnly Property BaseAttribute(ByVal GetValue As Boolean) As String Implements LDAP.CreationData.BaseAttribute
            Get
                If GetValue Then Return (Me.givenName + " " + Me.sn) Else Return "cn"
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Function ApplyCreate(ByRef Root As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry) As Boolean Implements LDAP.CreationData.ApplyCreate
            If Not LDAP.Connection.Add(Root, "cn", CObj(Me.givenName + " " + Me.sn)) Then Return False
            If Not LDAP.Connection.Add(Root, "sn", CObj(Me.sn)) Then Return False
            If Not LDAP.Connection.Add(Root, "objectClass", {CObj(LDAP.PosixAccount.baseclass)}) Then Return False
            Return True
        End Function

        Public Function Create(ByRef MainRoot As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry) As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry Implements LDAP.CreationData.Create
            Dim mRoot As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = MainRoot.Children.Add(Me.BaseAttribute(False) + "=" + Me.BaseAttribute(True), LDAP.PosixAccount.baseclass)
            mRoot.AuthenticationType = System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.None
            If Me.ApplyCreate(mRoot) Then Return mRoot Else Return Nothing
        End Function

        Public Function Apply(ByRef Root As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry) As Boolean Implements LDAP.CreationData.Apply
            If Not LDAP.Connection.Add(Root, "givenName", CObj(Me.givenName)) Then Return False
            If Not LDAP.Connection.Add(Root, "gidNumber", CObj(Me.gidNumber)) Then Return False
            If Not LDAP.Connection.Add(Root, "homeDirectory", CObj("/home/" + Me.uid)) Then Return False
            If Not LDAP.Connection.Add(Root, "objectClass", {CObj(LDAP.PosixAccount.baseclass), CObj(LDAP.PosixAccount.subclass), CObj(LDAP.PosixAccount.mainclass)}) Then Return False
            If Not LDAP.Connection.Add(Root, "uidNumber", CObj(Me.uidNumber)) Then Return False
            If Not LDAP.Connection.Add(Root, "uid", CObj(Me.uid)) Then Return False
            If Not LDAP.Connection.Add(Root, "loginShell", CObj("/bin/false")) Then Return False
            If Not LDAP.Connection.Add(Root, "displayName", CObj(Me.givenName + " " + Me.sn)) Then Return False
            If Not LDAP.Connection.Add(Root, "userPassword", CObj(LDAP.Security.Encryption.ToHash("12345678", LDAP.Security.Mode.SSHA))) Then Return False
            Return True
        End Function

        Public Sub New(ByRef FirstName As String, ByRef LastName As String, ByRef UserName As String, ByRef Password As String, ByRef UserNumber As Integer, ByRef GroupNumber As Integer)
            Me.givenName = FirstName
            Me.sn = LastName
            Me.uid = UserName
            Me.userPassword = Password
            Me.uidNumber = UserNumber
            Me.gidNumber = GroupNumber
        End Sub
    End Structure
End Namespace
```

Comment: also, don't use try catches for closing and disposing.. use either Using blocks, or Try Finally

Comment: Sorry, the Exception is DirectoryServicesCOMException, with the message "The requested operation did not satisfy one or more constraints associated with the class of the object."

Comment: Brett, ok i don't get error because of the Try Catch Finally block. I'm debuging without it exactly to get the exception type and message. It's quite simple really, the "Rename()" function for the DirectoryEntry class is returning the DirectoryServicesCOMException saying the requested operation doen't meet the criteria, but all i did was rename, the object is created correctly, with "cn=Teste Outro" then updated with lots of properties values but the rename does not work.

Comment: I beleave my bigest problem is this, i named the object "cn=Teste Outro". If i try to rename to anything like "cn=XXXXXXX" it works. The problem is that i want to rename in a way that it changes the mainattribute to "uid=teste.outro" (since "teste.outro" IS the UID - User Id - saved as you can see on the code). If i go to the LDAP server after my code runs i'll find a "cn=Teste Outro" saved, with all the properties of "inetOrgPerson" and "posixAccount". The "uid" attribute is from the "posixAccount" schema.

Comment: See Brett, i answered you below too :) In VB you CAN use "ABC" + "DEF" and it returns "ABCDEF" the same way if i did "ABC" & "DEF". That is not the error, since ALL MY STRING i concatenate using "+" instead of "&". The "+" operand can't be used if i try to concatenate a string with a integer for example (that i set as compiler error to prevent me from typing it). Anyway, that is not the exception. The exception is raised even if i place a String on Rename manually typed as "uid=teste.outro".

Comment: Thanks for reorganizing the question. I did copied the code in 1 single block with the objective to allow other people to copy and paste on the their IDE to test, but ok

Comment: And then, no more responses for some time... i find it hard to understand why this error happens... anyone?

Comment: UAU! This one is hard, no answers... i'm bypassing the problem to not need to rename, by creating the record already with the "uid=XXX" and worked. But i still need to rename DirectoryEntry classes on other nodes, so my problem is "half-way" resolved...